# Vb.net database connection falls over

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset

I've got the following code and I'm trying to update a new db row with the information. I'm pretty sure i've done it this way before but it falls over with a 'NullReferenceExcetption' on the line

```
dtItemsFeed = taItemsFeed.GetData()
```

The code (trimmed down) is as follows:

```
Public Partial Class downloaditems

    Private dtItemsFeed As dsItems.ItemsFeedDataTable
    Private taItemsFeed As dsItemsTableAdapters.ItemsFeedTableAdapter

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        checkSite("http://www.tiag.me/whatever/header.html", "Header")

    End Sub

    Private Sub checkSite(ByVal URL As String, ByVal Type As String)

        dtItemsFeed = taItemsFeed.GetData()
        Dim rFeed As dsItems.ItemsFeedRow

        rFeed = dtItemsFeed.NewItemsFeedRow

      ### Code that loads items ###

        rFeed.HeaderCode = sourcecode
        rFeed.LastImport = System.DateTime.Now
        rFeed.Verified = "True"

        dtItemsFeed.AddItemsFeedRow(rFeed)
        taItemsFeed.Update(dtItemsFeed)

    End Sub

End Class
```

The data works when I look through with edit dataset so I know it is connecting

error: [image]

Any help will be really appreciated. Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an object of `dsItemsTableAdapters.ItemsFeedTableAdapter`.

```
Private taItemsFeed As new dsItemsTableAdapters.ItemsFeedTableAdapter
```

Comment: Always such a simple thing! Thank you, was driving me nuts. Will mark as answer when time lets me

Answer (score 0):

You have no code that assigns a value to `taItemsFeed`.  Thus, it's always `Nothing` when you reach that code.

That or you've missed some essential code in your question!